# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined " while running script. It seems that variable "canvas" is undefined but I can't figure out why.

```
var world = {
    canvas: document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    context: this.canvas.getContext("2d"),
    centerX: this.canvas.width / 2,
    centerY: this.canvas.height / 2,
    drawShape: function (shape) {
        if (typeof shape.draw() === "function")
            shape.draw();
    }
};
```

Comment: Never mind, I figured out. I declared variable canvas outside of world literal and now it is working, but still I don't understand why you can't declare inside.

Comment: `this` is very weird in javascript. In your situation you would have to do 
`context: world.canvas.getContext("2d")`
if you don't want to add variables outside of world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I declared variable `canvas` outside of `world` literal and it is working

Answer (score 0):

An object literal doesn't establish a context for [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), so you can't refer to an object as `this` within its literal definition.

In your case `this.canvas.getContext` is probably being evaluated as `window.(undefined).getContext` because `window` has no `canvas` property.

You can save a reference to the `canvas` property and avoid `this`:

```
var world = {
    canvas: (var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")),
    context: canvas.getContext("2d"),
    centerX: canvas.width / 2,
    centerY: canvas.height / 2,
    drawShape: function (shape) {
        if (typeof shape.draw() === "function")
            shape.draw();
    }
};
```